# Proof that homotopy is a transitive property.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, solution-verification

I aim to prove that homotopy is a transitive property. If anybody could let me know if the following proof that I have constructed is correct, I would greatly appreciate it.

Let $\delta(t), \eta(t), \sigma(t)$ be three continuous well defined paths on an open set $U$ s.t. they are all defined for $t\in[a,b]$.

Suppose that $\alpha(t,h):[a,b]\times[c_1,d_1]\rightarrow U$ exterts a homotopy between $\delta(t)$ and $\eta(t)$ such that $\alpha(t,c_1)=\delta(t)$ and $\alpha(t,d_1)=\eta(t)$.

Similarly, suppose that $\beta(t,h):[a,b]\times[c_2,d_2]\rightarrow U$ exerts a homotopy between $\eta(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$ such that $\beta(t,c_2)=\eta(t)$ and $\beta(t,d_2)=\sigma(t)$. Note that by translation we can pick $c_2$ and $d_2$ for which $\beta(t,h)$ is defined such that $c_1<d_1=c_2<d_2$.

Thus one can define $\gamma(t,h) =
  \begin{cases}
                                   \alpha(t,h) & \text{if $h<d_1$} \\
  \beta(t,h) & \text{if $h\geq d_1$}
  \end{cases}$
with $\gamma:[a,b]\times[c_1,d_2]\rightarrow U$. We see that $\gamma$ is well defined and continuous on the interval and that $\gamma$ has the property that $\gamma(t,c_1)=\delta(t)$ and $\gamma(t,d_2)=\sigma(t)$. Thus $\gamma$ exerets a homotopy between $\delta(t)$ and $\sigma(t)$. Hence, since any path can be parametrised to any any interval it follows that for well defined paths on the same open set $U$ homotopy is a transative property.

If anybody could let me know if this proof is correct, or if it is wrong I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I think what you meant is $\alpha(t,c_1) = \delta (t)$ and $\alpha(t, d_1)= \eta (t) $. If that's what you mean then it seems to be okay.

Comment: @Uncool yes it was a typo, I have adjusted it now. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Yeah it looks fine to me. Just a minor note about your terminology though. You don't need to specify that a path is continuous and well defined, since a path is defined as a continuous map $f:[0,1]\to U$, or equivalently from any closed interval $[a ,b]$ as you use here. Also that "$\beta$ *exerts* a homotopy between $\delta$ and $\eta$" is unusual language. $\beta$ **is** a homotopy, it doesn't induce a homotopy or cause one to exist as the word "exert" might suggest.

Comment: @SeraPhim thank you very much for the suggestions. I have edditied this proof I have written such that it has the correct language in my notes. I will later update the post too. My question has been answered :)